# Adjust shower door that's not closing

Tags: doors, shower

Looking for suggestions to adjust our shower door that is no longer closing. The top corner is hitting the exterior frame.

It's a frameless door with a continuous screw-less hinge. I haven't been able to identify this specific type of door through the googler.

Questions:
- Can anybody identify the actual name of this hinge?

- Do you know of a good DIY video for this door / hinge type?

Thanks for any help or advice.[image][image][image][image]

Comment: need a pic of the entire door from the front, with the door in closed position

Comment: Thanks for looking, I added another photo showing the whole door.

Comment: In respect of the weight of the glass, which should be quite heavy, is it possible to lift by the handle and close the door completely? I suspect the glass is easing out the channel, and not the hinge wearing. If you can lift it and close, it is the hinge, if you can't lift it and close, the glass has changed position in the hinge channel. The 2nd picture from the top suggests that.

Comment: Would you call that a channel hinge?